# How can Iron Man's repulsor gauntlet work after Thor crushes it?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, the-avengers-2012

During the woods battle between Thor and Iron Man in the 'Avengers' movie, they get down to slugging it out toe-to-toe. Iron Man tries to punch Thor, who instead catches Iron Man's punch in mid-swing and proceeds to crush his gauntlet.

Iron Man responds by blasting Thor in the face using that now crushed gauntlet.

How can this be? Shouldn't the gauntlet have been disabled?

Note/Edit 
In the movie 'Iron Man', Stark shot up his own workshop while dressed in civilian cloths (no Ironman suite) and with only one gauntlet on. The power source/repulsor energy seems to be coming from the vambrace on his forearm, not the armored suit he wasn't wearing.

Comment: It all depends on what part of it got crushed. It could be the damage was cosmetic, or to the servomotors for fine hand control.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, pardon the pedant, but Thor does *not* crush the guantlet; he slightly crushes Iron Man's right forearm or vambrace, if you want to get technical. A gauntlet is a glove, the brace is the inner forearm and the vambrace is the outer forearm.

If you [watch the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeNbgEanR58&t=2m0s), around the 2:09 mark Thor crushes  Iron Man's right forearm (the outer shell) and the business end of the repulsor is in the palm.

In Iron Man's heads up display, the forearm goes red and a warning sounds; so his forearm is damaged but not enough to disable the repulsor in the glove.

So, this is a little speculation on my part, but I think it is plausible to conclude from the scene that the damage wasn't enought to disable the  repulsor.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Tony's heads-up display (showing the damage to the suit), it would appear that the arm piece is badly damaged but that the glove, which houses the repulsor, is totally unaffected. Note that damaged sections are red and undamaged sections are blue.

[image]

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Avengers,-The-(2012).html) indicated that they're losing power though...

> IRON MAN YANKS Thor right up. Thor grabs both HANDS BOOSTERS and
>   begins to CRUSH them. Tony quickly CHARGES as much energy as he can
>   and SHOOTS ENERGY in Thor's face.

Comment: Is the power source for the repulsor in the palm or in the gauntlet/vambrace? (nod to djm) Methinks the latter.

Comment: @Morgan - The power source for the repulsor is the glowie thing in Tony's  chest. I think we can assume that the wires run down the arm, hence why you see sparks when Thor squeezes it.

Comment: No actually it's not. Rewatch Iron Man movie paying special attention to the R&D phase of the disruptor developement. No chest power required.

Comment: @Morgan - I'm seeing an extensive wiring loop running from the repulsor, up his arm and along a black cable into his chestpiece. http://i.stack.imgur.com/BMWJy.png

Comment: You don't see him dressed in street cloths (no lronman suit) with only one gauntlet on, shooting up his workshop?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yr3gRpt.jpg Notice the two lines running back from the glove to the power source in his chest. He's not in the Iron Man suit, but at this point in the movies, the power for the repulsors still come from the arc reactor in his chest. This is why he runs out of power in the "old" arc reactor at the end of the movie and can't continue flying. The two are connected until much later (I think the Mark 42 in IM3 might be the first, because of its design).